# macro passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, avr-gcc

my code didn't build successfully with this error message:

```
macro "hton_us" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
```

and it occurs on this line:

```
hton_us( &fi.size, 1 );
```

here is the refrence to hton_us

```
void hton_us( iu16 *us, iu8 num )
{
    iu16 local;

    while( num-- ) {
        local=*us;
        *us++=swap_us(local);
    }
}
```

I read in some similar question that told to use `typedef` but it didn't help me.

Comment: Could it be that there exists a preprocessor macro with the same name as your function?

Comment: It's complaining that you already have a hton_us macro in addition to your implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a little C preprocessor trick, you can skip the macro and just call the function:

```
(hton_us)(&fi.size, 1);
```

By surrounding `hton_us` in parentheses, it tells the compiler that this macro cannot be expanded, because it wasn't called with any args, and thus the function gets called instead.

Comment: the marcin_j answer works fine. do you have any comment that which one is better?

Comment: @osyan it *works* or it *compiles*? (I know it's an old question: that comment is for future viewers :)). `ENDIAN_LITTLE` should be defined by the build environment *if* it targets a little endian platform. Defining it manually is dangerous (though most platforms are little endian, there are some big endian out there too).

Answer (score 3):

Check your header files, you probably have following there:

```
#ifndef ENDIAN_LITTLE
#define hton_us(us)
#define hton_ul(ul)
#endif
```

so probably ENDIAN_LITTLE is not defined

Comment: i use `#define ENDIAN_LITTLE;` and it works fine. do you thinks your solution is better than Richard answer?

Comment: actually you should not define this macro yourself but use some compiler defines to decide what byte order should be used. I dont know of any standard method for that, I have only found this on google that does something similar: http://androidxref.com/2.2.3/xref/external/dropbear/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_cfg.h